# Github's 'create merge commit' option for pull requests puts all the commits into a single one

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

So in my repository I have a branch called `patch` that I created from `master` in which I committed 6 commits. Then I created a pull request from `patch` in order to merge it to `master`. The pull request has been approved and when I merged it into `master` in Github using `create merge commit` option (which is the default option), strangely the merge created only one commit in `master` containing all the changes from the pull request's 6 commits, as if I had chosen `squash and merge` option (which I had not).

So I don't really understand what's going on with my repository. `create merge commit` option is supposed to merge the branch into `master` with all the new commits + an additional merge commit, but it's not behaving this way and I don't know why.

And What is even stranger is that `create merge commit` works fine in my other repositories. So I guess there is an option in this repository's settings that makes this problem occur, but I don't know where to look at.

Comment: For clarity: this is a question about using the GitHub web interface? (The one with a big green button, where you can select the merge, rebase-and-merge, or squash-and-merge options.) I've never seen it act this way myself, but if this *is* a question about that, then it's not about Git itself at all, but just about GitHub...

Comment: Yes, this is about the GitHub web interface.

Comment: Any ideas about this?

Comment: Not on my part—never seen it act that way myself, as I said. If you have a paid GitHub account, I imagine the GitHub support folks would be happy to help. They might even be happy to help even if you have a free account.